# prepend and remove from a ( void * ) in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, void

i think this is a pretty straight forward problem , but i still can not figure it out .

I have function which sends stream over the network . naturally , this takes const void * as argument:

```
void network_send(const void* data, long data_length)
```

i am trying to prepend a specific header in the form of char* to this before sending it out over the socket:

```
  long sent_size = strlen(header)+data_length;
  data_to_send = malloc(sent_size);
  memcpy(data_to_send,header,strlen(header)); /*first copy the header*/
  memcpy((char*)data_to_send+strlen(header),data,dat_length); /*now copy the actual data*/
```

This works fine as long as the data is actually char* . but if it changes to some other data type , then this stops working .

when receiving , i need to remove the header from the data before processing it . so this is how it do it:

```
void network_data_received(const void* data, long data_length)
{
 ........
 memmove(data_from_network,(char*)data_from_network + strlen(header),data_length); /*move the data to the beginning of the array*/
 ProcessFurther(data_from_network ,data_length - strlen(header)) /*data_length - strlen(header) causes the function ProcessFurther to read only certain part of the array*/
}
```

This again works ok if the data is char type . but crashes if it is of any different type .

Can anyone suggest how to properly implement this ?

Regards,
Khan

Comment: How do you call these functions?  Can you provide the code?

Comment: You're not computing data_length using `strlen` are you? Is that really the right function for your header too?

Comment: the problem lies in using (char*)data_to_send+strlen(header)

Comment: You might want to look at some of the scatter-gather socket APIs, this will save you unnecessary copies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `unsigned char *`  solved the issue . thankyou all for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like alignment could be the issue, but you don't specify which platform you're doing this on (different CPU architectures have different alignment requirements).

If the header's length is "wrong" for the alignment of the following data, that could cause access violations.

Comment: alignment is the issue infact , because sometimes i get invalid memory access when the data is of unsigned* type .

Answer (score 2):

Something surprise me in this code. Is your header actually a string ? If it is a struct, of something similar you should replace strlen with sizeof. Calling strlen on non zero terminated string is likely to cause crashes.

The second thing that surprise me is that when reading received data, you should copy the header somewhere. If not using it, why bother sending it over the wire ?

**EDIT:** OK, the header is some http like header string. There should not be any problem from there, and it indeed does not need to be analysed if you're just testing.

And you should move the data to the place you actually need it, moving it to the beginning of the buffer does not look like the right thing to do.

If the problem comes from alignment, it will disappear if you copy the data to some variable of the real target type at byte level before using it.

There is another solution: allocate your buffer with malloc and put the data structure you want at the beginning. Then you should be able to cast it. Addresses returned by malloc are compatible with any type.

Also be aware that if you were working with C++, casting to a non-trivial class is unlikely to work (for one thing vtables are likely to get a wrong addresses, and there is other issues).

Another possible source of problem is the way you get data_length. It should be a number of bytes. Are you sure it is not a number of items ? To be sure we need some hint of the calling code.

Comment: the header is : 
static const char* header="GET /images/logo.gif \r\n HTTP/1.1. \r\n Accept: /. \r\n Referrer: google.com. \r\n Accept-Language: en-us. \r\n Data:"

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy`'s behaviour is undefined if the source and target overlap (as in this instance) you should be using `memmove()`

What exactly is happening when what is not `char*`? These functions will generally cast to `void*` before actually doing any work...

Comment: when it is not char * , it still works , but on the receiving end it is messed up . because the data is encrypted ( very simple XOR encryption) . 

basically there are two types of data here:
char*
unsigned *
so i think i need to cast void* to some type which works for both of them . my knowlefge in C++ is limited due to lack of using it

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that `data_length` is not calculated correctly in the calling code.  Otherwise this code seems to be fine apart from possible alignment issues mentioned by @unwind.

How is `header` declared?  Does it have variable length?  Are you missing a terminating `NUL` character after the `header`?

Comment: the header is declared like this:
static const char* header="GET /images/logo.gif \r\n HTTP/1.1. \r\n Accept: */*. \r\n Referrer: http://www.google.com/. \r\n Accept-Language: en-us. \r\n Data:";

it is constant length of 122 . infact header is not the problem , the converstion to (char*) is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I'd also check to make sure that both sender and receiver use the same byte ordering architecture (little endian vs. big endian).